# How to disable generated navigation properties in Linqpad?

Tags: c#, json, linqpad

For look up tables with 1:1 relationships, LinqPad generates a property that points back to the collection of objects that use the lookup value.  How to disable this?

It's causing problems when I try to serialize tables using Newtonsoft.JSON.

Comment: You probably mean `n:1` relationships. Anyway, Linqpad is just a quick data access tool (and more). I creates a LINQ-to-SQL context on the fly and there's nothing you can configure about it. I even think it wouldn't be possible when using a context in project code.

Comment: How about `.Select(r=> new {r.c1, r.c2, ...})`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't prevent LINQPad from generating these properties, but you can tell Newtonsoft not to serialize them, with `IContractResolver`:

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size

Write your contract resolver class in the **My Extensions** query, so it will be available to all queries. In the CreateProperties method, where you filter the properties, you'll need to apply a condition on the property type to exclude navigation properties. The following will exclude all n:1 and 1:1 properties:

```
public class FlatResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
  public static JsonSerializerSettings Settings =
    new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new FlatResolver() };

  protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties (Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
  {
    IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties (type, memberSerialization);

    properties = properties
      .Where (p => !p.PropertyType.GetCustomAttributes (typeof (System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute)).Any())
      .ToList();

    return properties;
  }
}
```

And then to serialize, just do this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject (myObject, FlatResolver.Settings).Dump();
```

You can use similar logic to exclude 1:n, by checking for an IEnumerable of an entity type.